# Is recovering deleted apps possible yet?

Tags: ios, settings

With iOS 14 the Home Screen was altered to include an Activity Controller for confirmation of editing the Home Screen or deleting the app.

This has helped to avoid accidentally deleting apps but it's not foolproof!

Is there any way that you can find out which apps were deleted (In order of most recently deleted I'd imagine if at all possible)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. But you can see which apps are purchased, but not installed in the App Store, in your account.